# Chrome dev tools on all tabs

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to see a POST request that my browser is making on a certain form.

My problem is that the form is opened in a popup window (js initiated) and when the form is submitted it automatically closes the popup. So when I'm trying to use the developer tools' networking tab I can see the post request but don't have enough time to look into it since the window is closing too fast.

Even if I choose 'preserve log on navigation' it doesn't appear anywhere since the entire window is closing on submit.

Is there a way of opening the developer tools in the context of the entire Chrome application instead of a certain tab?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is. The best two solutions I can think of (that don't actually answer your question but I think achieve your aim) are:

1. Use another tool like Fiddler - http://fiddler2.com/ It's really good but only available for windows :(
2. It's a messy workaround but you could just comment out the line that closes the window while you carry out your debugging and then reinstate it once the issue is fixed.